# get cloudformation_facts for multiple cloudformation stacks with with_items in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have multiple clouformation stacks, and stored their names as a list in `CF_TEMPLATE_ITEMS`

Now I am trying to gather information about all of them (at the end I want to have the stack_output of all of them):

```
- name: Get all facts for all cf stacks
  cloudformation_facts:
    stack_name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ CF_TEMPLATE_ITEMS }}"
```

Unfortunately, afterwards `cloudformation` contains only the information for the *last* stack. It seems the information for the others are overwritten.

Can I somehow cat the facts for all cloudformation stacks from of list of stack names?

Comment: Is that entire play? I do not see `register`

Comment: cloudformation_facts stroes the result in cloudformations without the use of register

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I connect with this stack or any EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `cloudformation_facts` overwrites `cloudformation` fact with every run.

To collect data from every run, `register` loop result and reformat it to a clean dict, like this:

```
- cloudformation_facts:
    stack_name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ CF_TEMPLATE_ITEMS }}"
  register: cf_tmp
- set_fact:
    cf: "{{ dict(cf_tmp.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.cloudformation') | map('dictsort') | sum(start=[])) }}"
```

*This code is not tested.* This should give you `cf` dict with all your stacks facts as its keys.

Comment: How would you do that with `amazon.aws.cloudformation_info`? Now that `cloudformation_facts` is deprecated